# full word of we'd acronym word

Tags: word-usage, acronyms

What is the full word of the sentence which has the acronym word below?

> I guess we'd better do something about that!

The acronym word `we'd`.

When we use the phrase?

> we'd better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*We'd* is not an [acronym](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/acronym) but a contraction, in this case for **we had**. It can also stand for **we would**. A contraction represents the way we say a common combination of words in casual speech.

Comment: I got it, thank you